# Access Signal R via React using aspnet/signalr

Tags: javascript, reactjs, signalr

I am using the link below for implementing SignalR within react

[ASP NET Core Signal R Tutorial](https://codingblast.com/asp-net-core-signalr-chat-react/)

However, this code appears to not follow the current standards and @aspnet/signalr-client has now been marked as obselete with a message saying that @aspnet/signalr must be used

I managed to figure out that the accepted way for creating a hub connection is

```
// create the connection instance
var hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl("URL", options)
  .withHubProtocol(protocol)
  .build();
```

HOwever, I dont know how to call this within react?

I tried

```
import signalR, {} from '@aspnet/signalr';
```

but that gives the error

```
./src/components/widgets/Chat.js
Attempted import error: '@aspnet/signalr' does not contain a default export (imported as 'signalR').
```

Does anyone have an updated sample for Signal R with react or know how to do this now?

The package wont install as its obselete

Paul

Comment: Yeah you need websockets. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API

Comment: Is this the correct approach within react?

Comment: Sure, websockets are JavaScript API, that means they are native for React as well.

Comment: @Paul did my solution work for you?

Comment: yes thanks have accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom middleware, you dont 'NEED' websockets per se`
This is my current application:

configureStore.js:

```
import * as SignalR from '@aspnet/signalr';

//to server
export default function configureStore(history, initialState) {
const middleware = [
    thunk,
    routerMiddleware(history),
    SignalrInvokeMiddleware
];

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    ...reducers,
    router: connectRouter(history)
});

const enhancers = [];
const windowIfDefined = typeof window === 'undefined' ? null : window;
if (windowIfDefined && windowIfDefined.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__) {
    enhancers.push(windowIfDefined.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());
}

return createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware), ...enhancers)
);
}

const connection = new SignalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/notificationHub")
    .configureLogging(SignalR.LogLevel.Information)
    .build();

//from server
export function SignalrInvokeMiddleware(store, callback) {
return (next) => (action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "SIGNALR_GET_CONNECTIONID":
            const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
            connection.invoke('getConnectionId', user.userid)
                .then(conid => action.callback());
            break;
        case "SIGNALR_USER_JOIN_REQUEST":
            let args = action.joinRequest;
            connection.invoke('userJoinRequest', args.clubId, args.userId);
            break;
        default:
    }
    return next(action);
}}

export function signalrRegisterCommands(store, callback) {
connection.on('NotifyUserJoinRequest', data => {
    store.dispatch({ type: 'SIGNALR_NOTIFY_USERJOIN_REQUEST', notification: data });
})

connection.start()
    .then(() => {
        callback();
    })
    .catch(err => console.error('SignalR Connection Error: ', err));
}
```

index.jsx:

```
const store = configureStore(history);
const callback = () => {
    console.log('SignalR user added to group');
}
signalrRegisterCommands(store, () => {
    console.log('SignalR Connected');
    store.dispatch({ type: 'SIGNALR_GET_CONNECTIONID', callback });
});
```